# Firefox/IE IIS 6 Not Supporting Hiding Lables in Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I have some code that works on my IIS 5.1 dev box, but not on our IIS 6 production server OR in Firefox.  I'm hoping to find some code that will accomidate both our production server and Firefox.

Here's what's happening:

I have a label that should initially display as hidden.  I basically use this label to hide the entire row.

```
             <label for="lbCloseDate" id="lbCloseDate" style="display:none">
          <tr>
            <td bordercolor="#f0f0e4" bgcolor="#f0f0e4"><h3>Close Date</h3></td>
          </tr>
          </label>
```

Then, i use this javascript to unhide it, based on the value of a combo box:

```
    function statusShowHide()
{
    var cboStatus = document.getElementById('cboStatus');
    var lbCloseDate = document.getElementById('lbCloseDate'); 

    if cboStatus = 'Closed') 
    {
        lbCloseDate.style.display = "";
    }
}
```

Basically, what's happening in Firefox and our prod server is that the label/row doesn't hide.  I don't have an error; it's just not getting hidden like I want.

I don't need to use a label to hide the row...it's just the only way I knew how.  So, if something is more preferable that accomplishes the same goal, I'm open to it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your missing a ( here
also == for comparing, single = for assigning.

```
if (cboStatus == 'Closed') 
    {
        lbCloseDate.style.display = "";
    }
```

is it getting into this block?  if so, i'd recomend changeing the .display = ""; to .display = "none"

you can also just give your tr an ID, and use that to hide/show the row instead of the label.  will be more syntactically correct.

**EDIT:**

Here's a fiddle with a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2FDPg/

Here's the basics:

```
function showOrHideRow(){
    var theRow = document.getElementById('closeRow');
    var theDropDown = document.getElementById('ChangeMe');

    var theVal = theDropDown.options[theDropDown.selectedIndex].value;

    if(theVal == 'Closed'){
         theRow.style.display = 'none';   
    }
    else{
        theRow.style.display = 'block';
    }

}
```

and the html:

```
<table>
    <tr id="closeRow">

        <td>Close Date:</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>another row</td>
    </tr>

</table>

<select id="ChangeMe" onChange="showOrHideRow()">
    <option value="">Change me</option>
    <option value="Closed">Hide It</option>
    <option value="Open">Don't Hide It</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Still not working, unfortunately.  Also, using "" should make the label visible, shouldn't it?  It's not meant to be display "none" -blank string is essentially the same as "block" i thought, and more compatible with Firefox....unless i am wrong?

Comment: oh, i thought you were having trouble hiding it, not showing it!   what version of firefox are you using?